# How to edit controller in Sencha Architect 2?

Tags: sencha-architect

Editing of controller or any js file of sencha touch application bield from Sencha Architect 2 are editable or not?

Answer (score 1):

Manually or via the UI?

Manually you add a controller and then in the designer view choose CODE
and then OVERWRITE. 
The original is saved (look in the dir structure)

Next time open this screen, choose (in the first selector of code view) the VIEW OVERRIDE CODE
so that you see your latest work.

I work with intellij to edit the file. Then paste it into the field, and it automatically updates both files (there's a .js and an Architect metadata file)

Via the UI of course:  That's simple. Use the config inspector to select the views models and stores you wish to control.

Moshe

Answer (score 0):

If you are using architect each time you save the project architect edits the code of all the files in the app folder & app.html & app.js so any manual edits you make on the actual file will always be overwritten...

This is actually displayed as comment in each file eg:

```
/*
 * File: app/controller/MyController.js
 *
 * This file was generated by Sencha Architect version 2.1.0.
 * http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/
 *
 * This file requires use of the Sencha Touch 2.0.x library, under independent license.
 * License of Sencha Architect does not include license for Sencha Touch 2.0.x. For more
 * details see http://www.sencha.com/license or contact license@sencha.com.
 *
 * This file will be auto-generated each and everytime you save your project.
 *
 * Do NOT hand edit this file.
 */
```

I hope this was what you were looking for